# React Native: Set space between rows in a ListView

Tags: listview, react-native

I can't figure out how to set padding between my rows in a ListView. I am trying to replicate a card style feed looks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a `marginBottom` property to each ListView Item:

```
row: {
  ...
  marginBottom: 2
}
```

I've set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/uZFTfA).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, I can't believe I missed it. :)